# Как обновить определённый пакет в проекте до последней версии?

Tags: git, golang, github, update

У меня есть проект c зависимостями и один из них нужно обновить.

```
go.mod:
    require (
        github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin v0.0.0-20210329101903-fcd6d50e1db2
    )
```

Я уже внёс в данный репозиторий некоторые изменения и хочу использовать их в своём проекте.
Но как мне обновить версию пакета?

- `go get github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin` - обновляет пакет через раз.
- `go get -u github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin` - обновит все пакеты в go.mod.

Comment: левых пакетов не бывает.

Comment: создайте тэг на репозиторий PP-DF-Plugin, укажите этот тэг как версию `github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin v0.0.1`

Comment: @senior как уточнить при запросе `go get` что нужно скачать именно 0.0.1?

Comment: `go get github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin@v0.0.1`

Comment: Это не так. `go get -u github.com/....` обновит именно указанный пакет и его зависимости. А вот `go get -u` (без указания пакета) обновит все пакеты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

работая с Git, удобно ввести версионирование репозиториев с помошью тэгов.

Работая с модулями, вы должны указать версию используемого пакета, вот тут и пригодиться готовый тэг. Например,

```
require (
    github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin v0.0.1
```

можно добавить явные и не явные зависимости через команду

`go get github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin@v0.0.1` - по тэгу 
`go get github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin@master`- по имени бранча 
`go get github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin@08c92af`- по коммиту 
`go get github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin@latest`- последняя версия по тэгам. Может как повысить версию, так и понизить.

теперь ваш файл go.mod может выглядеть как

```
require github.com/c0caina/PP-DF-Plugin v0.0.1+incompatible // indirect
```

Суффикс +incompatible добавляется ко всем пакетам, которые еще не включены в Go Modules или нарушают его правила управления версиями.
Поскольку мы еще не импортировали пакет нигде в нашем проекте, он был помечен как `// indirect`. Мы можем привести в порядок наши зависимости следующей командой `go mod tidy` 
В зависимости от текущего состояния вашего репо, это приведет к удалению неиспользуемого модуля или удалению комментария `// indirect`.

Цель go mod tidy также состоит в том, чтобы добавить любые зависимости, необходимые для других комбинаций ОС, архитектуры и тегов сборки. Запускайте это перед каждым релизом.

[Документация](https://golang.org/ref/mod)

Comment: Хороший ответ, но вы забыли `@latest`.

Comment: спасибо, мастер